# How to compare 2 tables for matching values of a column in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a source table with ~40,000,000 unique/distinct entries and a new table with ~80,000,000 unique/distinct entries, both one columns each.

I need to create a flag column in the new table, which displays 1 if the corresponding observation's unique entry is also present(has matches) in the source table, and 0 if it has no matches.

How do I go about it most efficiently?

Is using *proc sql* inevitable, or can it be solved using SAS alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution for your reference:

```
/*step1: create a new dataset containing unique values of your new table*/
data new1;
    set you_new_table(keep=var1 var2 var3...varx);
proc sort nodup;
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
run;

/*step2: create a new dataset containing unique values of your old table*/
data old1;
    set you_old_table(keep=var1 var2 var3...varx);
proc sort nodup;
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
run;

/*step3: merge the two table that just created (inner join)*/
data compare1;
    merge old1(in=a) new1(in=b);
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
    if a and b;
proc sort;
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
run;

/*step4: merge the inner join dataset with the new source table and generate the flag*/
data new2;
    set you_new_table;
proc sort;
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
run;

data new3;
    /*merge new2(in=a) new1(in=b); sry, a mistake, shame.*/
    merge new2(in=a) compare1(in=b);
    by var1 var2 var3...varx;
    if a;
    if b then flag=1;
    else flag=0;
run;
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for a dummy dataset i created with 50 and 100 values. One small correction, in the line after "data new3;", it should be 'compare1' instead of 'new1' I think. Do you forsee any problems with large datasets?

Comment: also, what is the purpose to creating new2?

Comment: @Rohit 1) the line after "data new3;" is my mistake. I have fixed, thanks 4 pointing out.

Comment: @Rohit 2) dataset new2 is a sorted version of your new source table. The merge statement requires all dataset sorted by the same key vars.

Answer (score 3):

To add a new variable to a dataset you need to make a new dataset.  Assuming the data is already sorted on the key variable just do a MERGE.  You can use the IN= dataset option to check which datasets contribute observations to the merge.

```
data want ;
  merge new(in=innew) old(in=inold);
  by key_var;
  if innew;
  new_var = inold;
run;
```